# Hive SQL: How to create flag occurrence while join with other table

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql

I want to check whether my member from table A present in table B or not? Here is the problem is Both Table A and Table B has millions of records and table B have duplicate records. So that i cann't do left join. it takes hours to run.

**Table A**

[image]

**Table B**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Are the tables using a compressed splitable format like parquet/ORC?

Answer (score 2):

use this :

```
select member,
case when EXISTS (select 1 from TableB where TableB.member = tableA.member) then 1 else 0 end as Flag 
from tableA
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am facing this error "Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'member': Currently SubQuery expressions are only allowed as Where Clause predicates"

Comment: please share your sql version details.

Comment: Hive sql 2.0 (2.0.0)

Comment: this syntax probably wont work in hive, not sure

Comment: OMG. any alternate way to do this?

Comment: without join my be not supported this version. try to `union all` but may be same time to get  result compare to join.

Answer (score 1):

Not a very good solution but you can try this.
So, we use not in or not exists to get one set of data and then use in or exists to get another set. And then union them all together to get complete set.

```
select 
a.* , 0 flag
from tableA a where member not in ( select member  from tableB)
union all 
select 
a.* , 1 flag
from tableA a where member in ( select member  from tableB)
```

The trick may be, you can run 2 separate SQL for this and will get perf benefit instead of union all.

Not exist will work same way but can give you better performance.

```
SELECT a.*, 0 flag
FROM tableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM tableB b WHERE (a.member=b.member))
union all 
SELECT a.*, 1 flag
FROM tableA a
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM tableB b WHERE (a.member=b.member))
```